# Multiple embed paste PHP with hide/show dropdown embed

Tags: php, html

Hello guys I have an issue that I need everyone help on this with. I want to make something like this http://acidch.at/multipr2.php. However, I wanted to alter the design a bit more to my own method and apply it to something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yvasj8eq/3/. Here is the PHP script to the website linked above

```
    <?php

function pr2_embed ($width, $height) {
  $w = (string) (int) $width;
  $h = (string) (int) $height;
  return <<<HTMLcode_end
<embed width="$w" height="$h" base="http://external.kongregate-games.com/gamez/0001/0110/live/" src="http://external.kongregate-games.com/gamez/0001/0110/live/embeddable_10110.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
HTMLcode_end;
}

function get_value ($name, $default) {
  if (!isset($_REQUEST[$name])) return $default;
  return $_REQUEST[$name];
}

function create_page () {
  $rows = get_value("rows", 1);
  $cols = get_value("cols", 1);
  $width = get_value("width", 770);
  $height = get_value("height", 560);
  if ($width <= 0) $width = 770;
  if ($height <= 0) $height = 560;
  if ($rows <= 0) $rows = 1;
  if ($cols <= 0) $cols = 1;
  $i1 = (int) $rows;
  $i2 = (int) $cols;
  $display = pr2_embed($width, $height);
  $result = "";
  while ($i2) {
    for ($instance = 0; $instance < $i1; $instance ++)
      $result .= $display;
    $result .= '<br />';
    $i2 --;
  }
  return <<<HTMLcode_end
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Many PR2s!</title>
      <head>
      <body>$result</body>
    </html>
HTMLcode_end;
}

echo create_page ();

?>
```

The embed code for the "multiple pr2" is listed in the PHP script. But this is the embed code for the "Xat Chat": `

```
<embed src="http://www.xatech.com/web_gear/chat/chat.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="540" height="405" name="chat" FlashVars="id=1&gn=Lobby" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://xat.com/update_flash.shtml" /><br><small><a target="_BLANK" href="http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/embed.php?id=1&GroupName=Lobby">Get Lobby chat group</a> | <a target="_BLANK" href="http://xat.com/Lobby"> Goto Lobby website</a></small><br>`
```

I want the new design to be like the jsfiddle I posted above. The xat chat will be right below the multipr2 and will be distant by about 2  < p > perhaps. I would like to know if I can give users the ability to either exclude or include the xat chat like a drop down of whether they would like it or not. Thanks!